# Reference a named function in Excel starting from text

Tags: microsoft-excel

Let's suppose to have different named functions like:

```
Operator1(x,y, x+y)
Operator2(x,y, x-y)
Operator3(x,y, x*y)
```

Based on values in other cells we may obtain the named function number to use, i.e. 1, 2, 3, etc..
Is there then a way to call the proper named function by concatenating its name (e.g., "Operator"&1)?

Comment: `INDIRECT()` - may be of interest

Comment: What do you mean by named function? VBA?

Comment: Are these LAMBDA functions or UDFs?

Comment: If these are lambda functions in the named manager just create one and use CHOOSE to choose the correct function: `=LAMBDA(c,x,y,CHOOSE(c,x+y,x-y,x*y))`

Answer (score 0):

If these functions are LAMBDA functions, and supposing your number value for which function to use is in cell A1, your value for x is in cell B1 and your value for y is in cell C1, then:

```
=LET(n,A1,fn,CHOOSE(n,Operator1,Operator2,Operator3),fn(B1,C1))
```

You may want to also add some logic to constrain the value in A1 to a number between 1 and 3, such as:

```
=LET(
n,IFS(A1<1,1,A1>3,3,TRUE,A1),
fn,CHOOSE(n,Operator1,Operator2,Operator3),
fn(B1,C1)
)
```

The point here is that LAMBDA functions can be passed as parameters to other functions. You can watch my short video on this subject [here](https://youtu.be/QBW7dQDiEwI).